# How to do a .call or a .send transaction using web3modal + walletconnect 2.0?

Tags: walletconnect

I have the following code working, but I can't figure out how to make a .call or .send request after the web3Modal object has been initialized

Any help is really appreciated

Thanks in advance

```
import {
  EthereumClient,
  w3mConnectors,
  w3mProvider,
  WagmiCore,
  WagmiCoreChains,
  WagmiCoreConnectors,
} from "https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/ethereum@2.6.2";

import { Web3Modal } from "https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/html@2.6.2";

// 0. Import wagmi dependencies
const { mainnet, polygon, avalanche, arbitrum } = WagmiCoreChains;
const { configureChains, createConfig, getAccount, getContract } = WagmiCore;

// 1. Define chains
const chains = [mainnet, polygon, avalanche, arbitrum];
const projectId = "eab...";

// 2. Configure wagmi client
const { publicClient } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })]);
const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: [
    ...w3mConnectors({ chains, version: 2, projectId }),
    new WagmiCoreConnectors.CoinbaseWalletConnector({
      chains,
      options: {
        appName: "html wagmi example",
      },
    }),
  ],
  publicClient,
});

console.log("projectId", projectId);

// 3. Create ethereum and modal clients
const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiConfig, chains);
export const web3Modal = new Web3Modal(
  {
    projectId
  },
  ethereumClient
);
```

Answer (score 0):

what type of call do you want to make ? A contract call ? Or just an eth send ? As you're using wagmi, you can use wagmi's available actions like this example:

```
import { writeContract } from '@wagmi/core'

const { hash } = await writeContract({
  address: '0xecb504d39723b0be0e3a9aa33d646642d1051ee1',
  abi: wagmigotchiABI,
  functionName: 'claim',
  args: [69],
})
```

Check doc here: https://wagmi.sh/core/actions/writeContract